# Xcode 8: every time that I launch not swift 3 project, I have an alert

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

I see an alert about converting project to `Swift 3`. Is there any way to turn this alert OFF?

Comment: Just select `not now`, but since you are running project in Swift 3, some of the methods are deprecated hence you'll have to change those.

Comment: There is option "Later", to skip it.